# ArangoDB: Calling Python Dataframe in AQL language in a python code

Tags: python, dataframe, arangodb

I would like to use the python dataframe in the Arango Query as written below, and got stuck on how to use the df in the AQL query.

```
cursor4 = db.aql.execute(' for d IN Transaction filter d._to == %df 
    collect aggregate 
      length = COUNT_UNIQUE(d._id), 
      totamnt = SUM(d.Amount), 
      daysactive = COUNT_UNIQUE(DATE_TRUNC(d.Time, "day")) 
      return 
        { "Incoming Accounts": length , "Days Active": LENGTH(daysactive), "Total Amount": 
               totamnt} ')
```

Comment: Which client-library do you use? This doesn't loook like pyArango.  Normaly you use placeholders like `@name` and a `bindVars` parameter

Comment: I have used pyArango for this and Arangoclient as the client library.

Comment: `code` import requests
import json
from arango import ArangoClient

Comment: I'm confused pyArango IS the arangoclient library to use in python - see https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/pyArango#queries--aql how a query is supposed to work: `db.AQLQuery(aqlq, bindVars = {'placeholder': 'value'}...` with `@placeholder` in the query `aqlq`

Comment: Yes pyArango is the client that I have used in my python code. Now what I want to do is to use a dataframe which has a list of records which should be iterated in the arango query. Therefore in the line--> d._to==%df referes to the arango query referencing to the dataframe. This line is giving me an error.

Comment: Is this a documented feature? Can you point me to the docs describing the syntax?

Comment: I mean that embedding %X loops over the contents of the dataframe? do the records in the df contain  only a single element of the form `collection/key`? I would create an array holding the arango-ids, and change the filter to `FILTER @DF_ARRAY ANY d._to`, but if you can point me to the docs of what you are trying to do, I'll try to help further

Comment: No that is where I am getting an error, I just typed it for now, but in the place of df I wanted to know how can we use the python variable there.

Comment: Use an @placeholder and bindVars?!